# How to write ForAllMaps function

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I want to write code that checks, if source has `id` and destination has `SourceNameId`, than map, otherwise ignore. For example `Company.Id -> CompanyDto.CompanyId`

```
ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) => mappingExpression.ForMember($"{typeMap.SourceType.Name}Id", o => o.MapFrom("Id")));
```

Now `mappingExpression.ForMember` throws exception if cannot find `SourceNameId`.
It should not ignore all others members, mapped automatically or manually later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a check to see if the property exists in the destination type before trying to map it:

```cs
ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) =>
{
    if (typeMap.DestinationType.GetProperty($"{typeMap.SourceType.Name}Id") != null)
    {
        mappingExpression.ForMember($"{typeMap.SourceType.Name}Id", o => o.MapFrom("Id"));
    }
});
```